# dohttprequest is showing error of 400 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push message from the url below through JavaScript but it shows me error of 400. Please suggest me what I am getting wrong.

there was parameter issue in `doHTTPRequest`

```
var header = new Array();
var smsnotification;

var reply;
var url = "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/API/SendMsg.aspx?uname=XXXXXXX&pass=XXXX&send=LNTCON&dest=XXXXX&msg=Dear Team, VA alert Received from COC&priority=1&schtm=2018-09-9 18:07"


var h = new Header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
var hd = new Header();
hd.name = "Content-Type";
hd.value = "text/html"; 
headers.push(h);
headers.push(hd);
var data = "hello";

var smsnotification = doHTTPRequest("GET",url,headers,null,10,10,10);
print("15");
print("The result of the doHTTPRequest is \n"+ smsnotification);
```

Comment: Please add more context here. Where is `doHTTPRequest` defined? Is this front-end or node.js code? What is the expected result? (3 lines `var hd = .... "text/html";` can be just one, right?). Usually methods for making requests return an `xhr` object, not a response text, so `var smsnotification = ` doesn't seem to be the right way to deal with this.

Comment: I'm not sure what `doHTTPRequest` does but your url has spaces in so that's not going to work

Comment: rename the array to `headers`.

Comment: I want to send the text message from this script, when i tried to run the url from the browser its working fine but through script its running fine.... it shows me error.. please help me for the same  @YakovL Please suggest me how i can write to acheive the result.

Comment: show us the definition of `doHTTPRequest`, otherwise it's hard to help. Also add the error you are seeing into the question and describe where/when you see it

Comment: Dohttprequest definition mean?? i wouldnt get you on this?? and when i try to run this query it shows me error on var smsnotification line rest is okay for this....

Comment: JRTE E Error in doHttpRequest()
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://103.2xx.xx.xx/API/SendMsg.aspx?uname=20170079&pass=99NZv9D&send=LNTCON&dest=XXXXX&msg=Dear Team, VA alert Received from COC&priority=1&schtm=2018-09-9 18:07
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
 at com.hp.ov.sm.server.utility.HttpClient.doHttpRequest(HttpClient.java:223)
 at com.hp.ov.sm.server.utility.HttpClient.doHttpRequest

Comment: at com.hp.ov.sm.server.utility.TopazThread.handleRequest(Native Method)
 at com.hp.ov.sm.server.utility.TopazThread.processRequest(TopazThread.java:413)
 at com.hp.ov.sm.server.utility.TopazThread.process(TopazThread.java:339)
 at com.hp.ov.sm.server.utility.TopazThread.run(TopazThread.java:354

Comment: exact error i am getting

Comment: Wait, `java.io.IOException`? Is this Java? Then retag your question, JavaScript is a different language. Also edit your post and put the error log there, not in comments.

Comment: Also, have you tried what ths has suggested? You have a typo: `var header` instead of `var headers`